# Linux command line best practices and tips?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to open a discussion that would accumulate your Linux command line (CLI) best practices and tips.

I've searched for such a discussion to share the below comment but haven't found one, hence this post.

I hope we all could learn from this.

You are welcome to share your Bash tips, grep, sed, AWK, /proc and all other related Linux/Unix system administration, shell programming best practices for the benefit of us all.

Comment: Why Linux only? Many tips may be useful on almost all flavours of Unix.

Comment: This question might be a tad broad - there is enough to Linux/Unix command line best practices to fill entire books...

Comment: I agree that unix tips that can be applied to linux also are very much welcome, I've written linux because A. This is what we work with here. B. because it's gaining a more wider public exposure then unix in recent years.

Comment: I think it's a great idea to comiple a list of the most useful and interesting commands that people use.

Comment: Are any of these relevant?  http://refspecs.freestandards.org/

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing as "the" linux command line. There are at least half a dozen shells, all subtly different.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: That is true, but please agree that the common one is bash using either Konsole of Gnome-Terminal. So this list should still be relevant for most, quoting python zen: "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."

Comment: @Shane, on a second thought, yeah, this will probably work just fine, especially with the voting system bringing forth the best pieces of our common knowledge

Comment: I still think SU might have been the best suited trilogy site for this poll. If you look at the answers, most of them are general Linux "power user" tips whose usefulness is by no means limited to professional sysadmins.

Answer (score 111):

Use [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), a free terminal multiplexer developed by the GNU Project that will allow you to have several terminals in one.

You can start a session and your terminals will be saved even when you connection is lost, so you can resume later or from home.

Comment: The most common switches I use are 'screen -D -R' for detaching and resuming my last screen session and 'screen -x' to view the same screen session from multiple logins. Also, get yourself a nice .screenrc from http://dotfiles.org/.screenrc

Comment: Another nice thing about screen is that you can share a terminal with other people when you want to collaborate on something, using screen -x

Answer (score 101):

**SSH!**
SSH is the god command--I think it's the most valuable over-all command to learn.  The options can be pretty daunting, but it seems like I'm constantly learning to use new command-line options for SSH that I never thought would be necessary.  I may have used them all at this point.

The more you use it, the more you learn about it.  You can use it to do some AMAZING things.

Note: ALL these things are doable remotely with no setup on your server except to have ssh server running.

**Mount a file system over the internet**

search the net for SSHFS

**Forward commands**.

The SVN+SSH protocol is Subversion from a remote client to a server with NO DEAMON running on it!  The SVN command starts the server through the ssh shell and passes the info back and forth through the existing pipe.  The rsync program does the same thing, runs against a server with no rsync deamon by starting one itself via SSH.  It's easy to write your own bash files to do similar tricks.

**Chain to get through firewalls**

I use this all the time to jump through my linux server at home to my mac.

**Forward ports:**
Seems only moderately useful until you realize that you can bounce through your home firewall and configure your router at home from work as though you were doing so from within your home network).

**Forward X requests:**

This is another amazing one.  With or without an X server running on your remote system, you can run an x-windows program and the window will appear on your local screen.  Just use the switch -X, that's all!

Since you don't have to have an X server running on your remote server, the CPU impact on your server is minimal, you can have a TINY Linux server that serves up huge apps to your powerful game PC running Windows and cygwin/X.

Of course VI and EMACS work over SSH, but when I'm running at home, sometimes I want more.  I use ssh -X to start up a copy of Eclipse!  If your server is more powerful than your laptop, you've got the GUI sitting right there on your laptop, but compiles are done on your server, so don't worry about system load.

**Run in batch files**

(meaning run a local batch file that "does stuff" on other systems):

Two things combine to make this one cool.  One is you can eliminate password prompts by using (more secure) encryption keys.  The second is you can specify a command on the SSH CLI.  I've used this in some interesting ways--Like when a compile fails on the remote server, I would have it SSH into my computer and play a sound file).

Remember you can redirect the output from the remote command and use it within your local batch file, so you could also be locally tailing a compile running on your server.

**Built in to Mac**

Both server and client are built into both mac and linux.  In the case of the Mac and Ubuntu, enabling a server is as simple as finding the right checkbox.

On a PC install cygwin or cygwin/X (cygwin/X will allow you to forward your x-window output from your Linux machine to your Windows PC--it installs an X server)

**Important Tips/config file**

Never use port 22 on your firewall.  You'll get a lot of hack attempts, it's just not worth it.  Just have your firewall forward a different port to your server.

There are extensive configuration options that allow you to simplify your ssh commands significantly.  Here's an example of mine at work:

```
Host home
    hostname billshome.hopto.org
    Port=12345
    user=bill
    LocalForward=localhost:1025 mac:22
```

When I type "ssh home" (nothing else), it acts as though I had typed:

```
ssh -p 12345 bill@billshome.hopto.org
```

and then forwards my local port 1025 to my system "mac" at home.  The reason for this is that I have another entry in my file:

```
Host mac
    hostname localhost
    port=1025
```

so that once I've done an "ssh home" and still have the window open, I can type "ssh mac" and the computer at work here will actually try to connect to its own port 1025 which has been forwarded to "mac:22" by the other command, so it will connect to my Mac at home through the firewall.

**Edit--cool script!**

I dug up an old script I just love--had to come back and post it for anyone here who might be interested.  The script is called "authMe"

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub ]
then
    echo 'id_dsa.pub does not exist, creating'
    ssh-keygen -tdsa
fi
ssh $1 'cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys' <~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

If you have this script in your home directory and there is a host you can connect to (via ssh), then  you can type "./authMe hostName".

If necessary it will create a public/private keypair for you, then it will ssh over to the other machine and copy your public key over (the ssh command will prompt you for a password...)

After this, the SSH command should not ask for your password any more when attaching to that remote system, it will use the public/private keypair.

If your remote computer is not always secure, you should consider setting a "passphrase" when prompted.

You may also want to configure the ssh server on the far end to not allow text passwords (only keys) for additional security.

Comment: A small note on SSH over port 22: provided you've got a good root password and your users don't have terrible passwords, just running fail2ban (or something similar) is enough to keep out crack attempts. I found it really annoying to keep SSH on another port.

Comment: It can be irritating at times, but the volume of connects was just scary.  I know that they aren't supposed to get through, but it's kind of like if you had someone walking up to your house and fiddling with your doorknob every minute--just unnerving.

Comment: There's a built-in version of your last command in most versions of ssh nowadays, it's called `ssh-copy-id`, and it's as simple as `ssh-copy-id user@someserver`

Comment: Another way to do your 'ssh mac' trick is to use a ProxyCommand directive in your .ssh/config file.

Host mac
  ProxyCommand ssh -q home "nc %h %p"

This will run netcat (nc) on home and redirect your ssh connection straight through to mac.  I find those easier to chain (for example if you need to connect to 'home' to get to 'work bastion' to get to 'work web server'.

Comment: You might consider switching from dsa to rsa in your keypairs

Comment: Actually, a passphrase is more useful if the **local** computer is insecure.

Answer (score 73):

I like to use

```
cd -
```

to switch to the previous directory. Very useful!

Comment: I never knew this! Thanks! On a related note, pushd and popd do something similar, by building up a stack of dirs.  These sort of tricks help when you are navigating around a deep dir structure.

Comment: This is sheer enlightment.

Answer (score 69):

I've recently discovered the `pv` command (pipe viewer) which is like cat but with transfer details.

So instead of

```
$ gzip -c access.log > access.log.gz
```

You can use

```
$ pv access.log | gzip > access.log.gz
611MB 0:00:11 [58.3MB/s] [=>      ] 15% ETA 0:00:59
```

So instead of having no idea when your operation will finish, now you'll know!

[Courtesy of Peteris Krumins](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-pipe-viewer/)

Comment: $ gzip -c access.log > access.log.gz
Why not just: 
$gzip access.log

Comment: Oh that works :) I just took the example from Peteris' website.

Comment: That looks like good old `tee(1)`.

Comment: Extremely useful utility, one that I always forget about :-(

Answer (score 53):

```
sudo !!
```

Rerun the previous command as root.

[The current top command on the site http://www.commandlinefu.com, a site themed along the lines of this question.]

Comment: Disclosure - I run commandlinefu.com

Comment: It would have saved this guy 16 characters: http://xkcd.com/149/

Answer (score 45):

The command line is a funny thing.  I think that you can only learn so much on your own and the rest you learn by accident watching somebody else using a command line.

I was using the shell for years painstakingly typing in directory names by hand.  One day I was watching a friend mess around on a system and he kept hitting the tab key.  I asked "why are you hitting tab?".  Answer:  it tries to complete the directory or filename.  Who would have guessed--tab completion!  Type a bit of the file or directory, hit tab, and it will try to finish what you typed (behavior depends on which shell though).

One day, said friend was watching me on the command line and watched me type something like:

```
coryking@cory ~/trunk/mozi $ pushd /etc
/etc ~/trunk/mozi
coryking@cory /etc $ popd
~/trunk/mozi
coryking@cory ~/trunk/mozi $
```

Who would have guessed!?  He never knew about `popd` / `pushd`.  Guess we are even...

Comment: To me tab completion seems like something "obvious", very basic, but I never knew about popd/pushd either. Funny indeed. :)

Comment: Also see this answer to be able to tab-complete a lot more than commands, files and directories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603696//603919#603919

Comment: That's so true. I learned about bash's backward-history-search (ctrl-r) by watching someone. I later realized that it was a readline feature and worked the same in other programs that incorporate readline (mysql, gdb, python -i, clisp etc).

Comment: How could you use "the shell" for years and not know about tab completion?

Comment: When dealing with pushd/popd don't forget to mention the command **dirs**. It shows what's on the pushd/popd stack.

Answer (score 45):

Press **Ctrl-R** and start typing a command (or any part of it) - it searches the command history. Hitting Ctrl-R again will jump to the next match, enter executes the currently displayed command, and right-arrow (at least) will let you edit it first.

```
$ (reverse-i-search)`svn': svn status
```

I had used Linux for something like 7 years as my main OS before learning of this, but now that I know it, it's quite handy.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been using the reverse search, but haven't been able to figure out how to jump to the next match.

Comment: Ctrl-S jumps to the next match. You may have to do `stty -ixon` first to turn off the XON/XOFF flow-control meaning (this also makes Ctrl-Q available, by default it's mapped to be the same as Ctrl-V quoted-insert, but you can change it to something else). See `man stty` and `man readline` for more informations. The `stty` command can be added to your `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 41):

Learn Vim.

It is (arguably) the best editor, but most certainly the best editor available on a bare Linux server.

Comment: gvim is also best file browser on windows ;)

Comment: This is also extremely useful as once you know vim, you can put most shells into vi-mode, and navigation becomes extremely easy and fast

Answer (score 38):

It is sometimes useful to leave a program running even after you have logged out. I've seen some solutions that use nohup or even screen for that purpose. The simplest I know of is:

```
$ your_command_here & disown
```

You can also detach a running program:

```
$ your_command_here
# Press <Control-Z> to stop the program and bring it to background:
$ bg
$ disown
```

Comment: Using screen is great because you can "reconnect" to that app from anywhere later.

Comment: +1, I hadn't heard of disown.

Comment: ditto re disown, though I do already do the same with screen

Answer (score 38):

When I want to make sure that I use actual command and not an alias, I use a leading backslash:

```
\rm -rf ~/tmp
```

Comment: is this the same as "command rm -rf ~/tmp" ?

Comment: I didn't know "command", but it looks the same.

Comment: Well, yes unless the "command" is not alias in which case you would have to use
\command rm -rf ~/tmp
in that case
\rm -rf ~/tmp
is better

Comment: @presario and you think that would be possible to make an alias for "/"? What a pity I can't upvote the comments :)

Comment: See also the similar command "`builtin`".

Answer (score 38):

This tip will make your CLI more comfortable (at least it makes for me):

create ~/.inputrc file with following contents:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Reload bash (eg by typing "exec bash"). When you type a prefix of a command and press the up arrow you will browse commands starting with your prefix, for example if you typed ssh it will show your former connections with remote shells. If your prompt is empty then the up arrow will browse the history the normal way.

Comment: Usually I bind those to \e[5~ and \e[6~ (aka pageup and pagedown) instead of rebinding the arrows, but it is more convenient than Ctrl-R/Ctrl-S :)

Comment: It's also educational to read `man readline` and memorize it's default shortcuts

Comment: You can also do `bind -f ~/.inputrc` to reload the inputrc without having to start a new bash and wipe out your current environment.

Answer (score 36):

Use `&&` instead of `;` when executing multiple commands at once. It stops when an error occurs and does not execute the other commands.

Classical example:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: This practice is so underrated! It should be standard practice to end each line of a shell script with && and use "true" as the final command.

Comment: what's funny is that I didn't know about the ';' command before--I had ALWAYS used '&&'.

Comment: You can start shell scripts with "#!/bin/sh -e". This stops if any line fails.

Comment: You can use a double pipe for the "else" clause: `dosomething && echo "success" || echo "teh fail"`

Comment: There was a recent note on Planet Debian that it's bad practice to use the -e on the shebang line. Instead use set -e in the body of the script. This way the script doesn't work differently if someone happens to run in using sh $filename.

Answer (score 32):

When writing loops on the command line in bash I often prefix risky commands with the 'echo' command.

```
for item in items; do echo something-risky; done
```

This way I get to see the 'something-risky' in full before committing to run it. Helps when your risky command includes variable expansions and globs. And 'set -x' is very useful when writing bash scripts.

'set -x' enables debugging. See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html for information on bash debugging.

Comment: I do this too, very handy trick!

Comment: +1 This can be a life saver!  or data saver...

Answer (score 31):

### Requirement

You need to test maximum bandwidth between 2 servers.

---

### Solution

On **SERVER1** do :

```
nc -u -l 54321 > /dev/null
```

On **SERVER2** do :

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MB | nc -u SERVER1 54321 &
pid=$(pidof dd)
while (( 1 )); do kill -USR1 $pid; sleep 2; done
```

You will see output such as :

```
182682000000 bytes (183 GB) copied, 1555.74 seconds, 117 MB/s
182920+0 records in
182919+0 records out
```

**117 MB/s** is the interesting factor here, which shows the actual network transfer bandwidth.

**Explanation**:

As packet will start flowing over the network you will be able to see bandwidth statistics on SERVER2, which is a pretty good estimate of the actual maximum possible bandwidth between the 2 servers.

Copying by UDP (to prevent TCP overhead).

Copying to **from** memory (/dev/zero) on SERVER1 **to** memory (/dev/null) on SERVER2, thus preventing disk I/O from becoming the bottleneck.

Comment: Be sure that ssh is not configured to use compression in .ssh/config, 'though. Otherwise you'll get really nice numbers that are very far from the truth ;-)

Comment: Lol, yes. And SSH is going to be pounding your CPU encrypting and decrypting, which will also throw the numbers off.

Comment: use netcat instead

Comment: +1 for netcat. the overhead of SSH will skew your numbers

Comment: Refactored to amend suggestions by @saua, @Daniel Von Fange and @bendin.

Thank you for your suggestions guys.

Answer (score 23):

Seeing color directory structures is easier.

```
alias ls="ls --color=tty"
```

**Edit**

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

Comment: I prefer --color=auto because it doesn't sent rubbish control chars if redirect to file
you can also do
alias grep="grep --color=auto"
to have matching patterns highlighted.

Comment: +1 for --color=auto; could someone augment the answer with that?

Comment: I think tty does the same thing as auto here.

Comment: Updated to reflect the color=auto

Comment: Strangely, the coloring makes things much less readable for me. Yellow-on-white, for example, isn't a good coloring choice.

Comment: Not talking about the Yellow on white or green on black.  More about the ability to see the difference in the file types.  I.e. blue for directories, green for symlinks, etc...

Comment: You can change your terminal's colors. For xterm, use .Xdefaults, XTerm*background:  black
XTerm*foreground:  gray
XTerm*cursorColor: yellow
XTerm*color0:      black
and so on. If you have white background, often default colors don't work right.

Comment: In MacOSX: alias ls="ls -G"

Answer (score 20):

Some small pointers regarding log viewing:

1. You can use **tail -F** to keep watching the log after it is truncated (by example log4j).
2. You can use less: Open less, click **SHIFT+F** to emulate tail behaviour. Also useful combination is **-S**  to disable line wrapping. less will enable you to search in the logs.

Comment: And with `tail -f` you can watch multiple logs at once!  E.g.: `tail -f log1.txt -f log2.txt`

Comment: @StuThompson: Thanks. did not known that. Additionally, you might want to checkout http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

Answer (score 20):

I learned a trick from a [friend](http://sprocket.io/blog/2006/03/unix-shell-tricks/) a long while back to easily change a file's extension:

```
mv my_filename.{old,new}
```

Shell expansion will expand this to:

```
mv my_filename.old my_filename.new
```

This can also be used to rename a file in other ways, such as adding something in:

```
mv my_{,cool_}filename
```

Comment: Just be sure not to put any wildcards or other pattern expressions in the same command, or the glob could expand to more than just 2 arguments! mv *.{old,new} is likely to produce really surprising results.

Comment: Yes, agreed - this is an important caveat:)

Comment: You can also type, for example, `ls -l /bin/c` then press Alt-Shift-{ and it will complete this to something like `ls -l /bin/c{at,h{grp,mod,own,vt},p{,io},sh}` for you.

Answer (score 19):

Use "tar xf" to extract compressed archives. The j for bzip2 and z for gzip are not necessary, as tar will detect file type of your archive. Neither is '-' sign before arguments. You will save a lot of time (over a millenium ;-)).

Better yet use [unfoo](http://obsoleet.org/code/unfoo/) to extract any archive with a single command without any unnecessary arguments.

Comment: Yup, I have `alias ut="tar xf"` – makes extracting archives even easier.

Comment: This fails on some RHEL distributions, if you use them.

Comment: The new tar has also "J" switch for compressing to xz (7zip based) archives

Comment: Or install unp: http://packages.debian.org/sid/unp. I guess it is similar to unfoo.

Answer (score 17):

Install bash-completion package. It contains a number of predefined completion rules for shell. Enable it by typing "source /etc/bash_completion" if you distro doesn't do it for you. Then, for example whenever you complete after kpdf you will only see a list of directories and PDF files. It is as smart as to complete remote files after scp ssh://server/XXX (if you enabled passwordless logins).

Answer (score 17):

I use constantly these ones

ALT-.  (ESC+. in some terminals)   copies last used argument (super-useful)

CTRL-W  deletes word

CTRL-L  clear terminal (like clear command but faster)

ALT-B   (ESC+B in some terminals) move backward a word

ALT-F   (ESC+F in some terminals) move forward a word

CTRL-E  jump to EOL

CTRL-A  jump to BOL

CTRL-R  search in history

Comment: Thank you for sharing the shortcuts! I did not get ALT-B/F to work in Mac.

Comment: Awesome man....

Answer (score 16):

In bash, I use **!$** a lot.  It repeats the last argument of the last command:

```
ls /really/long/command/argument/that/you/dont/want/to/repeat.txt
vi !$
```

It will run the ls, then if you want to edit it, you do not have to retype it, just use !$.  This is really useful for long path/file names.  Also, **!*** repeats all the previous command's arguments.  I don't use that as much, but it looks useful.

I known they've been mentioned, but I use vim, screen, and cd - a lot.

I forgot noclobber:

```
set -o noclobber
```

From *man bash*:

> If  set, bash does not overwrite an
>   existing file with the >, >&, and <>
>   redirection operators.  This may be
>   overridden when creating output files
>   by using the redirection operator >|
>   instead of >.

Comment: I don't use $!, as it's really easy to fat finger, but I like hitting ^[-. (escape-period) to get the same effect.

Comment: Depending on your keyboard, etc., you can do `Alt-.` as well.

Comment: Omg, tiny orgasm, ty Dennis!

Answer (score 14):

Switch from bash to [zsh](http://zsh.sf.net/), and see your productivity improve:

- Really intelligent, scriptable tab completion. It completes not just command lines but all the options, names of man pages, package names (for apt-get / emerge etc), and what have you. And provides a helpful explanation of the options during the completion. All this without using any scrollback space after the command has been issued.
- Tab completion of wildcards; write cat *.txt, press tab, and choose between any files that match the expression.
- Switch directories just by typing their names.
- Several line editor modes. Can behave like vi or emacs if you want it to.
- Customizable key bindings to do whatever you wish.
- Themeable prompts, including the ability to put prompt information on the right side of the screen and have it auto-hide when typing a long command

Google will tell you many more benefits.

Comment: you should give more then a link.  sounds interesting, but sell it to me man!

Comment: Did they manage to include unicode support?

Comment: @Cory Alright, I just didn't want to plagiarize and it felt redundant to write my own when there's so much good stuff written by others already :)

Comment: @kyku yes, there's proper unicode support since maybe a year back.

Comment: looks cool.  i'll give it a shot!

Comment: the bash_completion package does have the same completion ability that you describe here, completion over ssh or anything else.

Comment: hmm, but zsh completes them and rotates the completion list inline too. you dont need to type anything but the TAB key :P

Comment: AFAI, bash completion doesn't do wildcards completion. tho you have echo as a kind of workaround.

Comment: Bash has most of the items in the list above: "rotating" completion: bind menu-complete to Tab, `vi` or `emacs` mode: `set -o vi` or `set -o emacs`, customizable key bindings via readline: show current settings with the -p, -P, -v and -s (and other) options to `bind`, prompts can be customized (a lot) but I wouldn't call them "themeable", switch directories just by typing their names: Bash 4 has `shopt -s autocd` to enable this

Answer (score 13):

Old school, moving a directory tree from one place to another, preserving symlinks, permissions and all that good stuff:

```
tar cBf - . | (cd /destination; tar xvBpf -)
```

or across the network

```
tar cBf - . | rsh foo.com "cd /destination; tar xvBpf -)
```

New school:

```
rsync -urltv . /destination
```

or across the network

```
rsync -urltv -e ssh . foo.com:/destination
```

Comment: `tar xvBpf - -C /destination` == `(cd /destination; tar xvBpf -)`  A little less typing, and easier to use over ssh.

Comment: -a is the same as '-rlptgoD' - that is recurse, copy symlinks as symlinks, preserve perms, preserve timestamps, preserve groups, preserve owners, copy device files and special files as device and special files.

Also, between machines, -z (compress files before sending, decompress after receiving) is useful.

rsync -avz [-e ssh] is your friend :-)

Comment: Does -z do any good over ssh?  I wouldn't think so.

Comment: `rsync -avh` is best on a single machine - the `h` ensures that hard links are transferred correctly without turning each link into a separate file, though if you have enormous numbers of files it can use a lot of memory. `rsync -avzh . foo.com/destination` is the equivalent for the network, and usually you don't need the `-e ssh` as rsync will know to use ssh.

Comment: Actually, these days I'm using `rsync -aSHuvrx --delete / --link-dest=/backup/$PREV /backup/$HOUR`

Answer (score 13):

**Requirement**: You have a directory containing large list of files you would like to delete. rm -r will fail!

**example**

```
find /var/spool/mqueue/ | wc -l
191545
rm -f /var/spool/mqueue/*
-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

**Solution**:

```
find /var/spool/mqueue/ -xdev -exec command rm -f '{}' +
```

**Explanation**:

*Edit: Fixing explanation following @ephemient comment.*

find will supply arguments to rm by the maximum allowed arguments. This will allows rm to delete files in batches which is the fastest technique that I know of without using the -delete operation of find itself.  It's equivalent to

```
find /var/spool/mqueue -xdev -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

which you may find useful if your `find` does not support `-exec ... +`.

Comment: Replace `\;` with `+`: then `find` will do what `xargs` does by default, which is batch up arguments as much as possible (without running over the argument list limit).  Or just use `-delete` intead of `-exec rm` (GNU Findutils needed for both)

Comment: Good tip - I didn't know the '+' one.

Comment: @ephemient: Good comment, I've edited the post.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard of '+'.

Comment: or just `find ... -delete`, if your find is so endowed.

Answer (score 11):

I use this two tips so often that i thought it would be a good idea to share :

```
!foo
```

Will launch the last command in the history file beginning with "foo" (I often use it when compiling, `!gcc` for example.)

The other one is a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+O instead of Return) this will execute the command AND display the next command in the history file. For example when I compile and test a file i always do 3 or 4 commands, make, cd to the dir of the test, run the test, cd to the dir of the makefile. Using Ctrl+O this makes this task a lot easier :)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 10):

How to use subversion in Linux without the help of fancy graphical interfaces that may not be available.

```
svn co <repo-url> . # Checks out project into current folder

svn update # Get latest changes from server

svn status # Shows what files have changed locally

svn add <path/filename> # Add some file to the repo

svn commit # Commit your changes to the repo
```

This holds back a lot of developers from using Linux, strangely enough.

Comment: rapidsvn is a nice little gui for svn under Linux.

Comment: Many fancy, powerful GUIs are certainly available (like that in IntelliJ IDEA), but I like the possibility of using either those or the command line (also powerful, but differrently) - whichever suits the current situation better

Comment: My favorite by far is NautilusSVN (much like TortoiseSVN): http://code.google.com/p/nautilussvn/

Answer (score 10):

Most overlooked old-school command: `find`

Yesterday I repaired a gross permissions bug:

```
for u in nr dias simonpj; do
   sudo -u $u find . -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' ';'
done
```

Comment: Yes! Learn the find command. Find mixed with xargs, sed and awk makes for a file processing juggernaut!

Comment: Agreed!  Although I never remember anything about sed and awk - I always need to relearn it!  I should really print out a cheatsheet.

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to use -print0 and the -0 option to xargs to avoid tricky problems involving filenames containing unusual characters (e.g. backslash).

Comment: Yup, probably half the time I use find it's to fix stupid permission things: `chmod 644 $(find . -type f)`, `chmod 755 $(find . -type d)`

Comment: Don't forget the `-perm` option to `find` to locate files that have permissions set a certain way.

Answer (score 8):

For shells like `bash` and `ksh`, you can make the command line respond to navigation commands like your text editor:

```
set -o emacs
```

or

```
set -o vi
```

will allow you to search your history and move about the command line in the way that you are used to doing in text files (e.g. in vi mode, pressing `ESC` then typing `/string` will search your previous commands for "string" - you can use `n` and `N` to move between matches)

Comment: Minor typo: "test editor" should be "text editor"

Answer (score 8):

grep is my friend. Seriously.

List `.rb` files that contain the text `class foo`:

```
grep -l "class foo" .rb
```

List `.rb` files that **don't** contain the text `class foo`:

```
grep -L "class foo" *.rb
```

List `.rb` files that **don't** contain foo or bar (you can use any regexp with -e, but you need to escape the operators):

```
grep -L -e "foo\|bar" *.rb
```

Comment: You might be interested in a tool called "ack", which does the same thing as grep but will scan recursively only sources files. Give it a try (it's free): http://betterthangrep.com/

Answer (score 8):

Shell substitution is performed with `^`:

```
/home/eugene $ ls foo.txt
foo.txt
/home/eugene $ ^ls^rm
rm foo.txt
/home/eugene $ ls foo.txt
ls: cannot access foo.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Actually I prefer "!!:gs/foo/bar" since I often find that foo is mentioned more than once in the previous command and I want a global replacement (e.g. "mv foo.txt foo.bak").

Answer (score 7):

`$_` is an environment variable for the last argument from the previous command

So if I create a new directory

```
$ mkdir ~/newdir/
```

To enter I simply go

```
$ cd $_
```

This is handy for complicated and large texts such as URLs, directories, long file names etc.

---

You can also refer to each argument in the previous command using `!:{number}`

```
$ echo !:0 !:1 !:2
```

Note that bash will expand this before you execute it (to see this press up to go through your history).

```
$ touch one two three
$ ls !:1 !:2 !:3
```

Unlike `$_` which is an environment variable, this will expand to 'ls one two three', perform the action and print the command to the shell. This method is a lot harder (in my opinion) to use than `$_` which I use much more frequently.

*Note: you can also use !$ instead of $_ but the former will expand*

Comment: A nice shortcut for getting the last argument of previous command(s) is M-. (aka (left) Alt-.) This will insert the same stuff as $_ with a single key press. Pressing it repeatedly will bring last arguments from previous commands. There's also a way of inserting other arguments,but I'm short of time

Answer (score 6):

There was an answer about using `pushd/popd` to remember directories. If you want to temporarily visit some directory, you can save typing by using `cd -` command, like this:

```
/home/eugene $ cd /etc
/etc $ cd -
/home/eugene $
```

Also, one of my favorite commands is `xargs`. I use it very often with `find`, but it can be also handy in other situations. For example, to find which command line arguments were used for starting some process, you can use the following command on linux:

```
 $ xargs -0 echo < /proc/[PID]/cmdline
```

In some cases (especially when working with source code) [ack](http://petdance.com/ack/) is more handy than `grep` because it automatically searches recursively and ignores backup files and version control directories (like .svn, .hg). No more typing long command lines like `find . -name \*.c | xargs grep 'frobnicate'`.

Comment: To temporarily visit a directory and jump back automatically, use a subshell: `(cd test; dosomething)` leaves you in the directory you started from.

Answer (score 6):

A nice one I've seen today from a friend.

Clean the log of the application (for next launch and co.)

```
> /var/log/appname.log
```

(Note the the **>** is part of the command).

This is the same as doing:

```
echo '' > /var/log/appname.log
```

Comment: That's kind of scary, actually... especially when you copy/paste from a terminal or website where the prompt ends with '>'...

Comment: The two commands are not equivalent.

The first one truncates the file (file is 0 bytes). The second one truncates the file and then adds a newline (file is 1 byte).

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/linux-tips-every-geek-should-know) is an excellent collection of tips I came across on digg today.

Comment: useful tips indeed

Answer (score 5):

I just finished reading [**Linux tips every geek should know**](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/linux-tips-every-geek-should-know) at TuxRadar. Very nice articles for those who know a little bit but want to know more.

Answer (score 5):

**[cut](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/)** and **[grep](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/grep/)** are a very nice way to manage plain text files. You can retrieve whatever you want. `cut` allows you to "vertical" split the file, and `grep` allows you to "horizontal" split the file.

The following sentence will split all the lines for `;` an only returns the 1 and 3.

```
$cut -d ';' -f 1,3 hello.txt
```

With **grep** (a well known command) you can do the same for lines. The following sentence will ignore the lines which have no interest for you:

```
$grep error hello.txt
```

`grep` can be also for reverse: ignore lines not matching the pattern and also you can use regular expressions.

But the **most powerfulness of both** are using pipes. For instance:

```
$grep error hello.txt | cut d ':' -f1,3 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: Neat picking: Once cut fails try awk, once awk fails do perl. Once perl sucks learn python.

Comment: s/^Neat picking/Nitpicking/

Comment: "Horizontal" `cut`: `sed '3,6p;d' hello.txt` will print line numbers 3 through six. More concise than piping `head` and `tail` together.

Comment: so much easier when you use the 'grep' built into awk..  awk -F; '/error/ { print $1, $3 }' hello.txt

Answer (score 4):

If you want to combine both stdout and stderr in a redirection, try using `2>&1`, as in:

`make > make.log 2>&1`

Comment: Same, but shorter (and less known): make &> make.log

Comment: @kyku: Nice! This should be it's own comment.

Comment: Let it be prize for those reading comments ;-)

Answer (score 4):

My ISP has a bandwidth cap, but a free-for-all window at starting 2 or 3am. So I schedule huge downloads for that window with `at`:

```
$ echo aptitude -d -y dist-upgrade | at 3am
$ echo wget http://example.com/bigfile | at 3am
```

The thing that originally confused me with `at` is that it takes the script on stdin, not on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `watch` command to repeat commands and observe results.  If it's not supported (as on Solaris systems), try the following (bash):

```
while [ 1 ] ; do
<cmd>
sleep <n> # n is # of seconds to repeat command
echo "" # meaningful output here can be helpful
        # I like to use ">>>>>>" `date` "<<<<<<<"
done
```

Comment: To sleep less then a second use usleep

Comment: Ahh, good point.  All my uses for this poll at 2-5 second intervals, but this is helpful as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
reset
```

or

```
stty sane
```

in case you ruin your terminal by accidentally catting a binary file!

Answer (score 4):

You can follow more than one file with `tail -f`:

```
tail -f logfile1 logfile2
```

the updates will be intermingled depending on the order of occurrence:

```
==> logfile1 <==
event-a
event-b
==> logfile2 <==
event-p
event-q
==> logfile1 <==
event-c
```

If you want a cleaner display, use watch and omit the `-f` from `tail`:

```
watch tail logfile1 logfile2
```

Comment: What an awesome tip.  I had no idea you could `tail` more than one file at once.

Comment: I just figured this out by accident yesterday.  I'm in love with this  trick.

Answer (score 3):

My personal, all time favorite: ***CLI meta and persistent aliases***.

with these aliases, one simple command (`val`) to define new shell aliases, and have them going forward.  concept can be extended to smaller "modes"/domains by additional alias files or aliases.

in ~/.alias.sh (make sure this gets sourced in your shell startup files)

```
# bash format example
alias sal='. ~/.alias.sh; echo ~/.alias.sh was sourced'
alias val='vi ~/.alias.sh; sal'
```

or ~/.alias.csh (*csh* format-- make sure it gets included in your shell start files)

```
# csh format 
alias sal 'source ~/.alias.csh; echo ~/.alias.csh was sourced'
alias val 'vi ~/.alias.csh ; sal'
```

Comment: +1 Cool, this looks like something I'll be making use of (with 'vi' replaced with some editor I can use :)

Answer (score 3):

My most common `ls` commands are

```
ls -lSr
ls -ltr
```

to sort files in order of increasing size and time respectively (to find the largest or most recent files).  Also, if you don't have a colour terminal for some reason, or don't like colours (like me) then `ls -F` gives you the same sort of metadata as colours: `'/'` indicates a dir, `'*'` an executable, etc.

Also, learn to use `find` and `xargs`: the power of the command line is cobbling together smaller commands into something more powerful.  These 2 commands are indispensible for that!

Comment: I cannot more agree with you - find and xargs are useful. If you are a mac user you need -print0 for find and -0 for xargs, since Mac uses spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 3):

here-docs are kind of fun:

```
cat << EOF > /tmp/file.txt

The ${speed} ${color} ${animal} jumped over the ${structure}

EOF
```

Or, if using BASH .. fun with here-docs in loops:

```
cat << EOF > /tmp/file.txt

The ${speed[i]} ${color[i]} ${animal[i]} jumped over the ${structure[i]}

EOF
```

Handy for generating HTML, PHP, configuration files, or damn near anything else inside of a shell script .. even other shell scripts :)

Answer (score 3):

Command-line editing keyboard shortcuts I use in bash:

**CTRL-U** - Delete text from cursor position back to home. Great for when you mistype a password, and don't remember if your terminal supports DELETE or BACKSPACE.

**CTRL-A** - Just like HOME key, even when your terminal doesn't send HOME correctly.

**CTRL-E** - Just like END

**ALT-F** - Move cursor forward by a word.

**ALT-B** - Move cursor backward by a word.

Comment: Also Ctrl+Right Arrow (Does the same as ALT-F)

Comment: That works for me only in Windows. when I try it in an ANSI terminal in putty it doesn't really work...

Comment: Ctrl-K cut from cursor position to end of line
Ctrl-Y paste last cut text, after which you can repeteadly press Alt-Y, which will paste older texts.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about the ALT-Y!

Comment: ^-Y is useful similarly as ^-U. I did not know that ^-U cleans and puts the removed text to your pbcopy. Thank you for sharing the pieces of information!

Answer (score 3):

Add this to ~/.bashrc

```
# expand things like !310:1 after spaces.
bind Space:magic-space
```

It's a bit scary to use

- !:0 (0th argument of last command, i.e. the program name)
- !:2 (2th argument of last command)
- !! (the whole of last command) (sudo !!)
- !$ (last argument of last command)
- !* (all arguments of last command)
- !ssh (last command starting with ssh)
- ^chunky^bacon (last command except the first chunky is replaced with bacon)
- !:gs\chunky\bacon (... all chunky is replaced with bacon)

without checking what's being substituted before running the command.

When you use wildcards like *.txt or globs like hello.{txt,org}, you can check what's being done with echo command beforehand.

```
echo rm *.bak
rm *.bak
```

But for stuff like !:0, you don't use echo, because once echo is done, the last command is the echo command. You may have heard of this phenomena as the "observation screw things" principle in quantum mechanics.

Instead, you just add "bind Space:magic-space" in your ~/.bashrc and then, whenever you press space, the stuffs like !:0 is expanded right there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one mentioned bash's built-in `fc` command (fc stands for Fix Command).

Use it to edit your previous command in an editor (i.e. vim) instead of in the command line, and execute it upon quitting the editor. Pretty handy.

```
fc [-e ename] [-nlr] [first] [last]
fc -s [pat=rep] [command]
```

Read more about it [here](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/bash/bashref_73.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Search in a gzipped file without first unzipping it:**

```
gzcat someFile.gz | grep searchString
```

Comment: Similarly, bzcat works on bzip2'd files. Quite handy for patches that are distributed bzipped - bzcat patch.bz2 | patch -p1 avoids the need to extract it somewhere temporary.

Comment: How about zgrep, zless and zxpdf? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A few useful ones:

```
rsync -av old_location new_location
```

will copy a directory structure and preserve permissions and links.

```
sudo updatedb && locate filename
```

to find files quickly (requires findutils)

```
apropos term_or_terms
```

searches the manpages.

Answer (score 2):

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Comment: That is a standard no-no.  One day, you'll not have the alias set, and then you'll accidentally remove something precious.

Comment: I use this too, but I don't depend on it.

Comment: I have a script called `rn`: `mkdir ~/.rm 2>/dev/null; mv "$@" ~/.rm;` This makes a wastebasket that in ~/.rm from where you can rescue stuff that should not be removed. When you disk is running full empty the wastebasket: rm -rf ~/.rm

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself thinking "oh, I can just write about 15 lines of Perl/Python/whatever to do what I want", first take a look at the [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can do path substitutions to change dirs by using 2 args with `cd`:

```
$ pwd
/foo/bar/blah
$ cd bar bat
/foo/bat/blah
```

Comment: What shell? What option enables this? It doesn't work for me in Bash 3.

Answer (score 2):

use expect !
This makes scripting interactive tools much easier. For example you can script telnet session, or ftp session.

Do your work on the command line, and then just script it. Here is a crude example, to telnet on a developement board, retrieve a kernel image, and put it into flash

```
#!/bin/bash
# scripted telnet
IP=$1
IMAGE="platform-AT91SAM9260/images/linuximage"
cp $IMAGE /home/cynove/public_html/
expect -b - <<EndOfTelnet
spawn telnet $IP
expect "login"
send "root\r"
expect "#"
set timeout -1
send "wget -O kimage http://192.168.10.2/~cynove/linuximage\r"
expect "#"
send "ls -al kimage\r"
expect "kimage"
send "flashcp -v kimage /dev/mtd1\r"
expect "Erasing"
expect "#"
send "exit\r"
EndOfTelnet
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the following commands which gives you Google and Google books in terminal

```
#!/bin/sh

q=$1
w=$2
e=$3
r=$4
t=$5

open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$q+$w+$e+$r+$t&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a"
```

and Google books in terminal

```
#!/bin/sh

q=$1
w=$2
e=$3
r=$4
t=$5

open "http://books.google.com/books?q=$q+$w+$e+$r+$t"
```

I have the following in .bashrc

```
alias gb='/Users/Mas/bin/googlebooks'                                                                               

alias g='/Users/Mas/bin/google'
```

I have permissions 777 for the scripts at /bin/googleScripts/.

**Examples**

```
gb Strang null space            // searches books which have the words

g Lordi Hard Rock Eurovision   // Googles websites which have the words
```

It would be cool to have book titles in terminal so that you do not need an external browser.

Similarly, it would be useful to have Google searches' urls directly in Terminal such that you can process the data in Terminal.

Comment: What's with the variable assignments? Just use the positional parameters directly. Also, I think `open` is Mac-specific.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite cli trick is to get out of CLI.

```
xdg-open .
```

This opens a GUI file browser with the current directory. That's for Linux. Use "START ." for Windows and "open ." for OS X)

Before I learned to use echo, I was afraid to use rm with wildcards, so I would xdg-open the current folder and then remove files in GUI. I was also afraid of the tar command, another reason to use xdg-open.

What about a way to get back to the CLI world?

Double-click (or triple-click) on the location bar of your GUI file browser and run:

```
cd "$(xsel)"
```

[that is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361798/command-substitution-but-without-breaking-output-into-multiple-arguments).  (or use open-terminal-here with nautilus)

Answer (score 2):

**Safety at the Command Line**

Experienced sysadmins do things that appear lazy or idiosyncratic at first, but save their bacon once in a blue moon.

**Don't Type Anything You Can Paste**

Prefer copy and paste to typing, whether you're copying from a run book, manual, or just higher in the terminal window. It's all too easy to type the wrong argument, switch, command, filename, etc., especially when you're simultaneously looking at systems, reporting status on a conference call, and trying to figure out the root cause of a problem.

Pasting the command line is a good habit. We should enable it by a) making everything scriptable and b) putting commands in manuals instead of screenshots.

**Differentiate Windows**

"Oops, wrong shell!" Famous last words. Find some way to separate windows that log in to different environments. Give production environments a different background color, or put them on a different monitor.

**Don't Trust the Path**

An oldie, but goodie, is to make a shell script called "ls" in your directory. Make it suid root, have it create a suid root copy of /bin/bash in a hidden directory of your own, then delete itself and run the real /bin/ls.  All you need to do then is get a naive admin to run "ls -la" in your directory and *poof*, you've got a root shell.

Real admins never have "." in their paths, exactly to avoid this kind of sneak attack. You shouldn't either. Adding "./" to the front of nearby executables is a good habit to get into.

**Don't Move Files. Copy Then Delete**

"mv oldname newname" is dangerous. It can destroy two files at once. It's better to do a sequence. Copy the origin file to the destination, check whether it's OK, then delete the original. Better yet, wait until you're totally done with the whole process, then remove the original file. Better yet, make a safe copy of the file you're about to change. The goal is to make everything completely reversible, so you can always get back to a known state.

Answer (score 2):

### Quick & Simple data integrity verification

using nothing more then bash & md5sum

This can prove to be priceless in terms of debugging trouble when moving binary files over the network... You should embrace this technique as common practice for each copy of valuable data to ensure 100% data integrity.

## Setup some test data...

```
mkdir -p /tmp/mdTest/dir{1,2,3}
for i in `seq 1 3`; do echo $RANDOM > /tmp/mdTest/dir$i/file$i ; done
```

## md5 hash calculation on the test data

```
cd /tmp/mdTest/
TMPMD5LIST=$(mktemp); (find  -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \;) > $TMPMD5LIST; mv $TMPMD5LIST list.md5sum
```

## data integraty verification from the hash

```
cd /tmp/mdTest/
md5sum --check list.md5sum
./dir3/file3: OK
./dir1/file1: OK
./dir2/file2: OK
```

#### Unit test: Let's break one of the files.

```
echo $RANDOM >> /tmp/mdTest/dir1/file1
md5sum --check list.md5sum
./dir3/file3: OK
./dir1/file1: FAILED
./dir2/file2: OK
md5sum: WARNING: 1 of 3 computed checksums did NOT match
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bash parameter expansions](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-parameter-expansion) are great:

```
$ FOO=leading-trailing.txt

$ echo ${FOO#leading-} # remove leading match
trailing.txt

$ echo ${FOO%.txt} # remove trailing match
leading-trailing

$ echo ${FOO/-*/-following} # match a glob and substitute
leading-following.txt
```

Need to rename a bunch of files? Combine with a `for` loop:

```
$ for FILE in file*.txt; do mv -v $FILE ${FILE#file-}; done
file-01.txt -> 01.txt
file-02.txt -> 02.txt
file-03.txt -> 03.txt
```

Once you have a basic grasp on them you'll be surprised how often they're useful.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes while working in terminal you need to open a file using some GUI application associated with it like for pdf or mp3 files. You don't have to remember the exact name of that command, just use:

```
gnome-open some-file.pdf
```

BTW, the shortest alias I use is:

```
alias o=gnome-open
```

Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

***My Favorite And Frequently Used:***

***List contents of tar.gz file***

tar -tzf filename.tar.gz

***will match line containing S1 OR S2 OR S3 OR S4***

grep 'S1.*S2.*S3.*S4' file

***Lists all subdirectories of current directory***

ls -d */

**Total size of directory**
du -sh

***find a date:***

TIMESTAMP=`date '+%y%m%d%H%M'`

***move process from foreground to background***

Ctrl-z and then bg

***Entire word to uppercase***

echo "word" | awk '{print toupper($0)}'

***Checks equality between numbers***

x -eq y         Check is x is equal to y

x -ne y     Check if x is not equal to y

x -gt y     Check if x is greater than y

x -lt y     Check if x is less than y

***Checks equality between strings***

x = y  Check if x is the same as y

x != y  Check if x is not the same as y

-n x Evaluates to true if x is not null

-z x Evaluates to true if x is null

***Command Line Parameters for ' test '***

-d      check if the file is a directory

-e  check if the file exists

-f  check if the file is a regular file

-g  check if the file has SGID permissions

-r  check if the file is readable

-s  check if the file's size is not 0

-u  check if the file has SUID permissions

-w  check if the file is writetable

-x  check if the file is executable

***print first field of the last line"***

awk '{ field = $1 }; END{ print field }'

***important build in variables***

$#  Number of command line arguments. Useful to test no. of command line args in shell script.

$*  All arguments to shell

$@  Same as above

$-  Option supplied to shell

$$  PID of shell

$!  PID of last started background process (started with &)

Comment: This might be more useful if you splitted separate tips (like the "build-in variables") in separate answers, with short justification and example for each. And maybe skip those 'test' parameter lists altogether - people can find that kind of stuff in manuals and reference guides.

Answer (score 1):

I'm moving towards never typing "rm" at a command prompt.  Instead, I type "ls", and if I like the list of removed files I edit the command (easily possible with bash and ksh).

Edit to add something from the comments:  "rm -i" will prompt for each deletion, which accomplishes the same purpose.  Thanks!

Comment: Please explain, I can't understand what you mean?

Comment: Typing something like "rm *.txt.bak" is a little error-prone; if you type "rm * .txt.bak" by mistake you're in trouble.  Therefore, I'll type "ls *.txt.bak" to see if I'm selecting the files I think I am; then I use bash shell command-line editing to substitute "rm" for "ls".

Comment: How do you do the command-line substitution? There must be a faster way than hitting up, home, delete, delete, r, m.

Comment: I don't know of a faster way.  I type faster and better than most people I hang out with, and it seems that I am willing to type more than they are.  I think that in csh and tcsh ^ls^rm or something like that worked.

Comment: Using 'rm -i filename' works for me.  It will prompt me to remove the file.  I actually aliased rm to 'rm -i'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some simple networking with bash (credit to this [page](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/01/two-cool-bash-tricks.html) and man bash):

```
cat < /dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13
```

Yes, writing to and simultaneous reading-writing is also possible.

Comment: Alas, Bash from Ubuntu doesn't seem to have this feature enabled :-( Wait for newer version.

Comment: I beleive this is because Bash from Ubuntu isn't compiled with the option to enable networking. Don't know what reasons keep them from enabling it. But I couldn't find a proper use for this feature anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Above all, understand anything you see in the internetz before trying it out in your dev box.

Comment: This is especially true if you see "Oooh! Neato! Try this!" and it turns out to be a fork bomb. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then neither of:

```
find . -exec ...
find . -print0 | xargs ...
for i in *.png; do ... done
```

works for processing a list of files, since one needs the combined power of find, NULL separated filenames as well as plain shell loops. The solution is this little bit of bash code:

```
find . -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' filename; do echo $filename; done
```

That allows one to process NULL separated files in a normal loop.

Comment: What is the problem with the third? for i in *.png; do...done?

Comment: GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ seems to be better suited for this, as it can run jobs in parallel. The while-read loop can be rewitten as:

find . -print0 | parallel echo

Watch the intro video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 1):

[Shell-fu](http://www.shell-fu.org/) is a place for storing, moderating and propagating command line tips and tricks. A bit like StackOverflow, but solely for shell. You'll find plenty of answers to this question there.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick:

When I want to make a bash alias, I just make a bash script on my user bin folder.

For instance, instead of adding the following line to my .bashrc,

```
alias make-symlink='ln -s -iv'
```

I'd make the following script and save it as ~/bin/make-symlink

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
ln -s -iv "$@"
```

, once the script is made executable (chmod +x), it's like I have a new alias.

Now make-symlink can be used in xargs. Also when you use a different shell (ZSH, FISH, IPYTHON, ...), make-symlink is there too.

If you use emacs, you might want to add the following to your emacs init file.

```
;; Make scripts executable on save                                              
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p)
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'tee' command is really useful for when you are outputting to a file and want to see the progress at the same time.  This is especially helpful for when you are logging output to a file and need to watch it as it progresses.

Instead of doing something like:

```
./program > file &
tail -f file
```

You can use the tee command on one line:

```
./program | tee file
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep track of everything I do.  One command that I learned in college was 'script'.  This takes any output on your terminal and logs it to a file.  What I *didn't* learn in college is how to make every terminal a script.  Now I have this in my .login file:

```
exec script ~/.typescript/`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.$$
```

Make sure that ~/.typescript/ exists before you add that to the end of your .login file. :)

Answer (score 1):

- For smaller directory trees with documentation to browse

  ```
  find .
  ```
- To empty a file from shell

  ```
  > file.txt
  ```
- To return to my home directory

  ```
  cd
  ```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, *nix most important command ever is... man :)

Almost everything one needs to know can be found with man and using man prevents us from interrupting our co-workers. And dealing with interruptions is one of our biggest concerns...

Answer (score 1):

I dont these commands are in the above list...!!!

1. find . -name .svn -type d |xargs rm -rf

   Remove all .svn folders
2. bash -x script.sh

   print line and execute it in BASH
3. Ctrl + [

   the same as [Esc] in vim
4. shopt -s autocd

   Automaticly cd into directory
5. df -i

   View the current number of free/used inodes in a file system
6. sudo !!

   Run the last command as root
7. python -m SimpleHTTPServer

   Serve current directory tree at http://$HOSTNAME:8000/
8. netstat -tlnp

   Lists all listening ports together with the PID of the associated process
9. Below are some ways to number input.txt:

   cat -n

   $ cat -n input.txt
        1  123
        2
        3  456
        4
        5  789
        6
        7
        8  abc
        9
       10  def
       11
       12  ghi

Answer (score 1):

I found Git version control to be:

- Snappy
- A pleasure to use
- Useful for a projects of almost any size (100K to 100GB; 1 to 100k files)

Here is how I do it:

```
# Create new repository
# (for now, it will live in .git/ - a single directory)
git init

# Commit all I got so far
git add .
git commit

# Add new or modified files manually
git add *.c
git status
git commit

# Add all modified files
git status
git commit -a

# Redo last commit
git commit -a --amend

# View log
git log

# Reset everything (files and git history) back to 
# what it was at 96223554b3e3b787270b1f216c19ae38e6f83ca5
git branch this-was-a-mistake
git reset --hard 9622

# Everything is back in time
ls
git log
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy sums/averages/grouping with awk:

```
cat tests
ABC 50
DEF 70
XYZ 20
DEF 100
MNP 60
ABC 30

cat tests | awk '{sums[$1] += $2; tot += $2; qty++}\
   END { for (i in sums) 
     printf("%s %s\n", i, sums[i]); 
     printf("Total: %d\nAverage: %0.2f\n", tot, tot/qty)} ' 
MNP 60
ABC 80
XYZ 20
DEF 170
Total: 330
Average: 55.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Output Redirection.  When you're running something apend

> > ~log.txt

to capture the output for later.  Append

> >& error_and_log.txt

for errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

`pushd` and `popd` to temporarily switch to different directories.

So

```
pushd ~/tmp
```

will move you to that directory, but push your current location to a stack (so it can be nested).

Then

```
popd
```

to return to the previous location.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on inline mode for tab completion for Bash:

http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1690

Answer (score 0):

To open remote X application on you local machine do:

```
ssh -X remoteuser@removeHost
konsole
```

This allows quickly viewing graphical applications running on remote host yet using your machine as the graphical server.

Answer (score 0):

Copy selected text:

```
CTRL + SHIFT + C
```

...and paste it:

```
CTRL + SHIFT + V
```

Comment: You can paste the last selected text by clicking on the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

In bash to close file descriptors: FD>&-

Close stderr:

```
$ function echostderr() { echo $1 >&2; }
$ echostderr "now you see me"
now you see me
$ echostderr "now you don't" 2>&-
$
```

Or inside a script:

```
$ function echostderr() { exec 2>&-; echo $1 >&2; }
$ echostderr "now you don't"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS start any command or pipeline with # (comment) and remove it when you finish writing the command. Gives you a 2nd chance at spotting rm -rf / like things.

Answer (score 0):

Here are Collection of Linux, UNIX User Management Commands
http://www.linuxconfig.net/2009/11/16/linux-unix-user-management-commands.html

Answer (score 0):

Meta+. in bash for cycling through the last argument from previous commands. Great for running tail and grep in various combinations.

Comment: Note for OS X users: In Terminal, meta needs to be enabled under the Keyboard settings before this will work.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+] x   to forward search for a character "x", and 
Meta, CTRL+] x  for backward search. On most systems, Meta can be ESC or ALT.
For ESC, you press ESC then release, then combine CTRL and ], and then press the character to search for. For ALT, press down CTRL + ALT + ]  at the same time, then the target character.

I find it's useful when editing history command.

For very long and very complicated command. I use
fc
to open vi(probably actually vim on linux) to edit the command.

Comment: For long command editng, in bash at least, you can 'set -o vi' to enable vi-style keybindings directly in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a multiple files in a similar fashion I found the following script very useful and robust over the years.

It just puts the output of `ls`  into your favorite text editor. You just modify the text, save, close. The files are renamed accordingly.

It's especially great when you combine this with Vi column editing (`Ctrl-v`, select a block, `I` to insert before or `A` to insert after, type text, `Esc`).

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

RM = '/bin/rm'
MV = '/bin/mv'

from = Dir.entries('.').sort; from.delete('.'); from.delete('..')
from.sort!

from.delete_if {|i| i =~ /^\./} # Hidden files

tmp = "/tmp/renamer.#{Time.now.to_i}.#{(rand * 1000).to_i}"

File.open(tmp, 'w') do |f|
  from.each {|i| f.puts i}
end

ENV['EDITOR'] = 'vi' if ENV['EDITOR'].nil?
system("#{ENV['EDITOR']} #{tmp}")

to = File.open(tmp) {|f| f.readlines.collect{|l| l.chomp}}
`#{RM} #{tmp}`

if to.size != from.size
  STDERR.puts "renamer: ERROR: number of lines changed"
  exit(1)
end

from.each_with_index do |f, i|
  puts `#{MV} -v --interactive "#{f}" "#{to[i]}"` unless f == to[i]
end
```

I call this script `renamer`.

Answer (score 0):

To copy part of a file system to a new hard disk one can use

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
mkdir /mnt/newhd
mount /dev/sdb /mnt/newhd/
rsync -av --hard-links --acls --one-file-system --xattrs /home/maxim/ /mnt/newhd/
echo '/dev/sdb /home/maxim ext4 defaults,user_xattr,noatime 0 1' >> /etc/fstab
```